# How do I check why a Kubernetes webpage keeps loading?

Tags: python, docker, matplotlib, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I followed this Google cloud Kubernetes [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/quickstarts/deploying-a-language-specific-app#python) for python. I basically changed what's in their hello world function to plot with matplotlib (with some other functions beforehand to get data to plot). It all worked (with some changes to the dockerfile, to pip install modules, and use just python 3.7 instead of the slim version) until where it says to view a deployed app. I copy the external IP and try it in the browser, but it just loads. I'm not sure what to check to see why it won't finish loading.

So I'm wondering how I check where the problem is. The python code works fine elsewhere, outputting a plot with flask on a local computer

Comment: What endpoint are you using to connect to your service?

Comment: @Rico The external ip numbers? I follow the tutorial and it ouputs hello world when I try it without altering it.

Comment: What do you see?  a blank page and it just keeps on loading?

Comment: @Rico Yes I open a new tab and put the external ip address in, and the loading signal starts moving in the tab, but nothing changes on the page, it ran for hours. It may be a problem with flask, but how do I see what the problem is?

Comment: Just answered with some things try. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [proxying from your localhost directly to the pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) to see if there's a problem with the load balancer.

```sh
kubectl port-forward your-pod-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx <local-port>:<pod-port>
```

Then you can just hit `http://172.0.0.1:<local-port>` on your browser.

You can also take a look at the pod logs:

```sh
kubectl logs your-pod-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx
```

Comment: I tried ```http://172.0.0.1:<local-port>``` and it loaded awhile then the connection timed out.

Comment: I tried looking at the pod logs, and it ends up repeating many times of '[INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8 [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:8) [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)' up to pid 187 the last time I tried it. This question has come up before (gunicorn timeout) so that may have led me to where I want to go.

Comment: Sounds like it's trying to spawn gunicorn workers in the pod/container and it can't. It could be permissions and/or access to resources in the container.